# Use of "But for"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> "But for my help, he would not cross the entrance."
>
> "But for my helping him, he could not pass the exam."

Are both the sentences above correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences are grammatically correct, but this structure is uncommon in modern English, and would be unsuitable in common speech. You didn't mention the context of the sentences. If you want to use archaic or poetic language, they may be acceptable.

Note that since these are unreal past conditional sentences, you should use the perfect, "would not have crossed".

In modern English, more common ways to express these ideas are

> If I hadn't helped him, he could not have passed the exam .

Or (somewhat more formal)

> Had I not helped him, he wouldn't have...

Or simply

> Without my help, he wouldn't have...

Or as a compound sentence:

> He wouldn't have passed the test by himself, but I helped him study and he did it.

Comment: But ain't the above sentences simple sentence...Whereas conditional sentences are complex.Or is it the rule ?

Comment: These are conditional sentences in disguise. You are describing an imagined situation, an alternative past that did not actually occur; you should use perfect in these cases (it is pretty much required, not optional).

Comment: @laugh...Would you please convert the sentence into compound ?I really need it ...

Comment: Your sentences are not compound, despite the use of "but". I added another example. If you need something else, please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @Nehal: you should understand that "but for" is an EXTREMELY rare phrase (for example, I think I have NEVER heard it used in speech), and using it will always make your sentences harder to understand. I would recommend always using the "if he hadn't..., I wouldn't have..." construction.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct, although I don't understand what you mean by "cross the entrance".

The second sentence should read "but for me helping him...". You had the right idea, you just made reference to yourself in the wrong form.

Comment: why would "cross the entrance" be unconventional? When you can cross a street, a line, a border why not an entrance?